# 404 page not found while page redirection in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

Hi all I tried to redirect to dashboard controller addLocation function under admin folder i have given the link below its showing 404 page not found,

http://localhost/kooly/admin/dashboard/addLocation

This is my htaccess file help me to solve this redirection problem

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /kooly/
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and save outside of your application folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /your folder/

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|robots\.txt)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]    

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Comment: localhost/kooly/admin/dashboard

can you try if u can access this link?

Comment: yeah i can access that link.Now its working for me i have given Upper case letters in my url i have changed addLocation to addlocation now its working thank you @Gennia

Answer (score 0):

Try the below .htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteRule  ^/?ajax/(.*)$  ajax.php?$1 [NC,QSA,L]
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Still getting the same 404 page not found

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code into your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L] 

</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

It's working for me using codeigniter 3.

I hope it will work for you!!